# LPCTSTR to LPCSTR conversion

Tags: c++, string, winapi, file-handling

I am trying to get information of existing file using `GetFileInformationByHandle()`. My function that performs the required task receives `LPCTSTR Filename` as argument. Here is the code:

```
getfileinfo(LPCTSTR Filename)
{
    OFSTRUCT oo;
    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation;
    HFILE hfile=OpenFile((LPCSTR)Filename,&oo,OF_READ);
    int err=GetLastError();
    GetFileInfomationByHandle((HANDLE)hfile,&lpFileInformation);
}
```

Above code works fine if I declare `Filename` as `LPCSTR` but as per requirement of my function I receive the filename in `LPCTSTR` so if I use typecasting then `openfile()` cannot find the specified file and returns -1.

Can anyone tell me how to get file information if filename is `LPCTSTR`? Or how to convert `LPCTSTR` to `LPCSTR`.

Why is this typecasting not working? I believe this should work.

Comment: Do away with the `TCHAR`s and use the wide string versions of all Windows API functions.

Comment: Problem here being that the wide string version of OpenFile doesn't exist.

Comment: Assuming your building with UNICODE defined; All of your LPCTSTR are actually LPWSTR (WCHAR) at compile time. So a LPCSTR type cast on a LPCTSTR is usually going to be interpreted( by something that is deigned for a LPCSTR) as a single ASCII character followed by a 0x00 byte. And your going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to your immediate problem is to replace `OpenFile()` with `CreateFile()`, just like the [`OpenFile()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430(v=vs.85).aspx) says to do:

> **Note**  This function has limited capabilities and is not recommended. For new application development, use the CreateFile function.

For example:

```
getfileinfo(LPCTSTR Filename)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
        // handle error as needed ...
    }
    else
    {
        BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION FileInfo = {0};
        BOOL ok = GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, &FileInfo);
        int err = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (!ok)
        {
            // handle error as needed ...
        }
        else
        {
            // use FileInfo as needed...
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, a better solution is to not open the file at all.  Most of the information that `GetFileInformationByHandle()` returns can be obtained using [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) instead:

```
getfileinfo(LPCTSTR Filename)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData = {0};
    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(Filename, &FileData);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
        // handle error as needed ...
    }
    else
    {
        FindClose(hFile);
        // use FileData as needed ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just casting the pointer doesn't change the actual data (ie filename) that is being pointed to into eight-bit characters.

Reading [the docs at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests using `CreateFile` instead, which handles LPCTSTR filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Project Properties/Configuration Properties/General/Character Set.  This is normally set to UNICODE.  It can be changed to MBCS.

If it is set to MBCS, then the code does not need to be modified.

If it is set to Unicode, which I suspect it is otherwise you won't be asking this question, use widechartomultibyte to convert it from LPCTSTR (const wchar_t*) to LPSTR (const char*).